# how do i Wait for a string to change from null to some value and them collect it

Tags: c#, string

Collect value when it property changes, the method takes some time to get he string. I have to wait until the string changes from NULL to some value, after it changes i have to collect it and return. This are two Different Threads..

```
public static string k=string.Empty;    
public void SomeMethod()
{
k=someObject.Method(byte[]);// this returns some string this methods takes some time to execute
CollectMethod(k);
}

Public string CollectMethod(string K);
{
return k;// Return only when the k is not null
}
```

Comment: If you use your code `CollectMethod` "waits" already so long as `someObject.Method` has returned the string.

Comment: I assume these are running on separate threads? Otherwise this will run synchronously and all will be fine..

Comment: yes they are two different thread. I am scratching my head from 2 days for this issue

Answer (score 2):

just make k a property and include the `CollectMethod` call in the setter.

```
private static string _k;
public static string k
{
  get {
    return _k;
  }
  set {
    _k = value;
    CollectMethod(value);
  }
}
```

This way, even if your assigning the value from a different thread, `CollectMethod` will not be called until the assignment occurs.

When you intend to access the property from multiple threads, it is important to make the property thread safe. To do this, you simply need an object that you can `lock` on.

```
private static object kLock = new object();
private static string _k;
public static string k
{
  get {
    lock (kLock)
    {
      return _k;
    }
  }
  set {
    lock (kLock)
    {
      _k = value;
    }

    CollectMethod(value);
  }
}
```

This ensures that only one thread can access the property.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead Agreed. I'll include a bit on how to do that.

Comment: someObject.Method(byte[]);// is asynchronous I have to wait for it to change. And then collect it.

Comment: @gnsanvesh Correct. Now, in your `SomeMethod`, you only need to call `k=someObject.Method(byte[])`, and _when it returns_, it will call the setter of the property.

Comment: In the Constructor of the class I created a Event, when ever data is available i collect it. And I send the message request to the device separately I have to wait for the event to raise and delegate the message and then return it

Comment: Sounds like a different question from this one. This property should do the task you originally asked for. As far as the event stuff goes, just be careful how you write the event listener for it (and use this property as is appropriate). If you need more help with the event stuff, I'd suggest asking a new question.

Answer (score 2):

Use a [ManualResetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx) to pause one thread, and signal it from the other thread once the other method returns:

```
public static string k=string.Empty;    
public ManualResetEvent waitForStringEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);

public void SomeMethod()
{
    k=someObject.Method(byte[]);// this returns some string this methods takes some time to execute
    // After a while, someObject.Method() will return, and we'll signal the event
    waitForStringEvent.Set();
    // ...
}

Public string CollectMethod(string K);
{
    waitForStringEvent.WaitOne(); // This will block until signaled
    return k;// Return whatever is in k once signalled
}
```

Both threads can safely access the `waitForStringEvent` object.